# Architecturing ruby database access code with module

Tags: ruby, oop, couchbase

I'm a ruby noob and I'm a bit struggling finding the proper way to architecture my code.

In the code base, there is a Couch module that used to read:

```
module Couch
  def self.client
    @client ||= Couchbase.new "http://#{DATABASE_HOST}:8091/pools/default"
  end
end
```

Each time we had to access the database we would do:

```
Couch.client.get(...)
Couch.client.set(...)
```

for instance :

```
def Model

  def self.find(id)
    Couch.client.get("foo:#{id}")
    ...
  end

  def save
    Couch.client.set("foo:#{@id}", {...})
  end
end
```

The repetition of Couch.client everywhere and static thingy was making me inconfortable, I felt it was not the ruby way.

So I changed the Couch module to

```
module Couch
  extend Forwardable

  def_instance_delegators :client, :get, :set, :delete, :append

  def client
    @@client ||= Couchbase.new "http://#{hostname}:8091/pools/default"
  end
end
```

and in model class that want to use it

```
def Model
  extend Couch

  def self.find(id)
    get("foo:#{id}")
    ...
  end

  def save
    Model.set("foo:#{@id}", {...})
  end
end
```

I think it is better but I must admit I am not entirely satisfied with the way it looks...
Is it really OK to have a `:get` class method in my Model ? The name is a bit confusing. Should the module be included (with a ClassMethods submodule for instance) ? Can I avoid the class variable `@@client` (but I don't want a new connection to be created for each instance) ?

Bref, is there a better way ?

Answer (score 1):

> I think it is better but I must admit I am not entirely satisfied with the way it looks... Is it really OK to have a :get class method in my Model ? The name is a bit confusing. Should the module be included (with a ClassMethods submodule for instance) ? Can I avoid the class variable @@client (but I don't want a new connection to be created for each instance) ?

I don't think you should have a `get` class method in your Model; you're right that it makes no sense.

Your original method looks very good to me.

It's explicit, yet not too verbose. Anyone can understand what the code does, easily.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-ruby-model and couchbase-model rubygem itself. It does most of dirty job. Also if you have ideas/patches I'll be happy to review them. I'm using gerrit code review therefore the most recent patches are here http://review.couchbase.org/#/q/status:open+project:couchbase-ruby-model,n,z

Comment: this looks nice ! I'll have trouble migrating my existing models but I'll definitely try it next time I have to create a new model class.